# Как передать пароль команде scp?

Tags: ssh, scp

```
#!/bin/bash

scp ./file.tar admin@test.tr.ria:/home/admin
set pass "53td87Ysb"
```

При запуске скрипта, требует ввод пароля. А как сразу передать пароль?

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях используется аутентификация по ssh-ключу вместо пароля.

Comment: А как это прописать в bash скрипте?

Comment: В скрипте ничего менять не придется. На машине откуда копируете генерируете/находите ключ, на сервере - добавляете для пользователя открытый ключ. Подробнее по ссылкам https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-SSH-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0 и https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: ссылки на инструкцию по git, но он работает поверх того же ssh, что и scp